# Mapping Im(z)>0 to a shifted circle - Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I want to map $Im(z)>0$ to $|z-i|<1$ using a Möbius transformation. I have a simple question regarding that. I know I can choose 3 points on the domain boundary and map them to the circle, but it is quite tedious. Can I know which point will be mapped to the center of the circle $|z-i|=1$? I can then use the preservation of symmetry to find the transformation. I saw somewhere that I can say $f(i)=i$ in this case, but I have no idea why it is ensured $i$ will go to the center of the circle and not any other points inside the $Im(z)>0$ domain.

Comment: Do you know the standard way of mapping the upper half plane onto the unit disc? Once you figure this out, you just have to perform a translation. If you use this line of reasoning, then the "simplest" mapping takes $i$ in the upper half plane to the origin of the unit disc, so after translation, the origin is mapped to $i$. Hence, $f(i)=i$. Note of course this is not the only possibility (it's just the most obvious), because once we map to the unit disc, we can apply any automorphism, and this can move points around, so that it is no longer the case $f(i)=i$.

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean that if I choose for example $f(2i)=i$, I'll get a different mapping function that does the same mapping of $Im(z)>0$ to $|z-i|<1$ ? I thought the mapping should be unique. Where am I wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: Yes, there are several possible maps. Say $f_1$ maps $H$ (upper half plane) to $D_0$ (unit disc centered at origin). We know that by a translation $T:D_0\to D_i$ we can map the disc at the origin to the disc at $i$. So, $T\circ f_1$ maps $H$ to $D_i$. This is only one possibiity. There are infinitely many more. For any automorphism $\lambda:D_0\to D_0$, $f:=T\circ\lambda\circ f_1$ also maps $H\to D_i$. The question of which point of $H$ is mapped to $i\in D_i$ depends very heavily on $\lambda$. Of course, to keep things simple we would take $\lambda=\text{id}$, but that's not the only choice.